# Read user input until ESC is pressed in C

Tags: c, input

Is there a way to read user input until the ESC key(or any other key) is pressed? I've seen forums about it but they've all been for C++. I need to make one that works for C. Thanks

Comment: this will need to be platform specific if I recall correctly. What platform are you running this on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's check 'esc' character in ascii table:

```
$ man ascii | grep -i ESC
033   27    1B    ESC (escape)
$
```

Therefore, it's ascii value is:

- '033' - Octal Value
- '27' - Integer Value
- '1B' - Hexadecimal Value
- 'ESC' - Character Value

A **sample program** using integer value of 'ESC':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int c;

    while (1) {
        c = getchar();            // Get one character from the input
        if (c == 27) { break; }  // Exit the loop if we receive ESC
        putchar(c);               // Put the character to the output
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps!